# PySpark : KeyError when converting a DataFrame column of String type to Double

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to learn machine learning with `PySpark`. I have a dataset that has a couple of `String` columns which have either `True or False or Yes or No` as its value. I'm working with `DecisionTree` and I wanted to convert these `String` values to corresponding `Double` values i.e. `True, Yes` should change to `1.0` and `False, No` should change to `0.0`. I saw a tutorial where they did the same thing and I came up with this code

```
df = sqlContext.read.csv("C:/../churn-bigml-20.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)

from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction

binary_map = {'Yes':1.0, 'No':0.0, 'True':1.0, 'False':0.0}
toNum = UserDefinedFunction(lambda k: binary_map[k], DoubleType())

csv_data = df.drop('State').drop('Area code') \
    .withColumn('Churn', toNum(df['Churn'])) \
    .withColumn('International plan', toNum(df['International plan'])) \
    .withColumn('Voice mail plan', toNum(df['Voice mail plan'])).cache()
```

However when I run this, I get so many errors that look like this.

```
  File "C:\..\spark-2.1.0\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 70, in <lambda>
  File "C:\..\workspace\PyML\src\ModelBuilding.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    toNum = UserDefinedFunction(lambda k: binary_map[k], DoubleType())
KeyError: False
```

**Note**: I'm working on PySpark with Spark 2.1 and Python 3.5 and I guess the tutorial that I follow uses spark 1.6 and Python 2.7. So I don't if this is one of the Python grammar issues.

Comment: are the string in the columns with Quotes?...i think the reason might be the string in column might be "No" instead of No

Comment: Nope. I checked the data set and they don't have qoutes. They are just plain string values.

Comment: why aren't you using binary_map.get(k)? i think it should be raising another error of accessing the dictionary with []

Comment: I'm new to Python. I'm learning Python as well as Machine Learning. I followed a tutorial to try the same flow and execute it. So if you see any issues/syntax error with the code, please correct me where I'm wrong. I want to learn and correct my mistake.

Comment: my bad...i think that works in python 3.5,my mistake can you add the whole traceback?the full error

Comment: Yep. Added that now.

Comment: can you try defining the function abit like def toNum(s): binary_map = {'Yes':1.0, 'No':0.0, 'True':1.0, 'False':0.0} return binary_map[s] and in new_function=userdefineFunction(lambda k:toNum(k);doubleType())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142134/discussion-between-eliethesaiyan-and-de-santa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing mapping part to:

```
binary_map = {'Yes':1.0, 'No':0.0, True : 1.0, False : 0.0}
toNum = UserDefinedFunction(lambda k: binary_map[k], DoubleType())
```

I just removed the quote from True and False. I thought that was weird but when I checked the schema of the `DataFrame` using `print(df.printSchema())`, it showed that the field that has True and False values is of type `boolean`.

**The Schema**

```
root
 |-- State: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Account length: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Area code: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- International plan: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Voice mail plan: string (nullable = true)
  .
  .
  .
 |-- Customer service calls: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Churn: boolean (nullable = true)
```

So that's why I had to take the quotes off. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed. Now I understand we need to have an eye for the detail. People say "having a thorough knowledge of the data that we are working with is a must". Now I know why. Anyways, thanks. :)